# How to wire this transformer in series (both primary and secondary)?

Tags: transformer

As above.

This is my guess but need some expert input.

Violet+grey on the primary.
Black+yellow the secondary.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Violet to grey makes the primary (brown/blue), black to yellow makes the secondary (red/orange).  However winding both in series makes little sense.   You'd get the same output voltage ratio with lower copper resistance loses by connecting both sides parallel.

Comment: @KyleB my V+/V- supply uses center-tap for ground.

Comment: @KyleB But how does that affect VA?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The primary

If you have a 120V supply, then it is Hot to brown/gray.   Neutral to violet/blue.

If you have a 220-240V supply, then you splice violet and gray *only to each other*.  And then, hot to brown and neutral to blue, as usual.

### The secondary

You haven't said anything about what you want.  I'm going to give you North American style "twice the secondary voltage with a center-tap", as might be used with a half-wave rectifier.  So in that case you tie together black & yellow to be your center point.   Red is now your pole L1, and orange is your pole L2.   It's AC so it is not the case that red is + and orange is -.  It is half the time.